# DKIM_INVALID in Spamassassin only for emails sent from other emails in the same server

Tags: dovecot, dkim, spamassassin, opendkim

I have postfix/dovecot running with spamassassin on Centos.

**PROBLEM:**

- The VPS acts as a mail server
- Spamassassin edits the email subject and adds [SPAM}
- Ms. Outlook on Windows moves those emails to the Junk folder
- The above happens ONLY if an email is sent from the VPS to another address on the same VPS machine
- The above problems does NOT happen if I send emails from this VPS to another email account on antoher server that also uses Spamassassin

I have Wordpress blogs with WP_SMTP plugin. And they're configured to use SMTP to send emails.

When I send emails from contact forms on the blogs, I receive emails in the "SPAM" folder.
I noticed that the headers are:

```
spamd[12042]: spamd: result: . 0 - ALL_TRUSTED,DKIM_INVALID,DKIM_SIGNED,HTML_MESSAGE,T_SCC_BODY_TEXT_LINE scantime=30.1,size=3544,user=vmail,uid=994,required_score=5.0,rhost=localhost,raddr=127.0.0.1,rport=56530,mid=<023501d860a6$aba8e580$02fab080$@mydomain.com>,autolearn=no autolearn_force=no
```

WP_SMTP has a test feature. I can choose to which email address send a test email.
If I choose one of the email addresses handled by my post server, they also are marked with `DKIM_INVALID`.

However if I send exactly the same test email to mail-tester.com this is what I get: https://www.mail-tester.com/test-5oyf5qlg5

10/10 and DKIM is fine.

Also [dmarcian](https://dmarcian.com/dkim-inspector/?domain=anahatatantra.com&selector=default) says DKIM is fine.

When I send an email from my server to a different email on my server (on different domains), they also get `DKIM_INVALID`.

Can anyone please help to make spamassassin stop marking emails sent from Server X to Server X as spam (DKIM_INVALID)?

Or maybe I can get more info, logs, etc that can help to find an answer to this problem?

**IMPORTANT!**
The server is using `Unbound`. I had to use Unbound, because Spamassassin was reporting:

```
ALL_TRUSTED,DKIM_SIGNED,DKIM_VALID,DKIM_VALID_AU,FROM_IN_TO_AND_SUBJ,HTML_MESSAGE,MIME_HTML_ONLY,T_SCC_BODY_TEXT_LINE,URIBL_BLOCKED
```

And I was told that many blacklisting services don’t allow queries from freely available DNS servers, and that includes (or may include) whatever DNS my provider provides me fro DHCP/

As soon as I start to use Unbound and I change

```
/etc/resolv.conf
options trust-ad
; generated by /usr/sbin/dhclient-script
search localdomain
nameserver 62.149.128.4
nameserver 62.149.132.4
nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888
```

to:

```
nameserver ::1
nameserver 127.0.0.1
options trust-ad
```

Spamassassin stops adding `URIBL_BLOCKED` and starts adding `DKIM_INVALID`

**EDIT - new test on [dkimvalidator](https://dkimvalidator.com/)**:

```
DKIM Information:
DKIM Signature

Message contains this DKIM Signature:
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=anahatatantra.com;
    s=default; t=1651780260;
    bh=WOwAVylmbsjOThr0t5u3PrLcNjOVp9SrbUgzVixBh7I=;
    h=From:To:Subject:Date;
    b=DCJ9L1ik8gcbohyaqB4pXqcmqa32+Y3F7sbSDnqQ7M1S0D/5/MdfEd1b2MIh8HQfB
     Mpui8c2TdpbDSmakosk99bgBPjFHe5i3cW1lmxJKrIlT5/wBvRVejg+PtmnIbIre+S
     XNakG1D1AzcUmpv2fBVoZGFv+0eT9Hub0LM5ouV4=


Signature Information:
v= Version:         1
a= Algorithm:       rsa-sha256
c= Method:          relaxed/simple
d= Domain:          anahatatantra.com
s= Selector:        default
q= Protocol:        
bh=                 WOwAVylmbsjOThr0t5u3PrLcNjOVp9SrbUgzVixBh7I=
h= Signed Headers:  From:To:Subject:Date
b= Data:            DCJ9L1ik8gcbohyaqB4pXqcmqa32+Y3F7sbSDnqQ7M1S0D/5/MdfEd1b2MIh8HQfB
     Mpui8c2TdpbDSmakosk99bgBPjFHe5i3cW1lmxJKrIlT5/wBvRVejg+PtmnIbIre+S
     XNakG1D1AzcUmpv2fBVoZGFv+0eT9Hub0LM5ouV4=
Public Key DNS Lookup

Building DNS Query for default._domainkey.anahatatantra.com
Retrieved this publickey from DNS: k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCXSuXbbxQjrqMX01rwXL8qMwUxCZrjFPnZokm6TyCj9bY5c96148UKFfiOWcfAhTmIC//pL3f08Pk8scBSM34pRQ8mYQhhjnXR2JMPIeJOZ9eAparHJfxk6PNd/5O/aXzVC+1RFtSWLaUilnA+Jdafkhe/4zZ8/kKMuzxaatGXcwIDAQAB
Validating Signature

result = pass
Details:
```

The test passes.

Thus seems to me there is no difference to emails sent "outside", for example to mail-tester, or dkimvalidator.

The problem seems to be only server related, when emails are sent from the same server to the same server.

Comment: I've updated the question. In https://dkimvalidator.com/ it always has the same status. No matter if I configure `/etc/resolv.conf` with `nameserver 127.0.0.1` or `nameserver 62.149.128.4`. However Spamassassin in my server detects DKIM_INVALID if emails are being sent using `Unbound` and  `/etc/resolv.conf` with `nameserver 127.0.0.1`. And are VALID (but fires the `URIBL_BLOCKED` rules if `/etc/resolv.conf` has the nameservers it receives from DHCP. Only inside the same machine. Outside doesn't seem to have any difference in tests.

Comment: dont use public resolver

Comment: I confirm that "body has been altered" is not an issue as it's related to some unicode signs in the email. If I sent email with different text the signature passes with `result = pass`. Thus I confirm that the problem is only with Spamassasin inside the same machine that sends emails.  Outside in external servers all is fine. 

P.s. I don't understand what I can do otherwise. I stopped using the DNS I used to receive by DHCP. Now it's using `Unbound`. Thanks to this the rule `URIBL_BLOCKED` is not firing anymore.